# Dynamic linking on mobile platforms

Tags: iphone, android, cocoa-touch, blackberry

I have heard that the iPhone does not support dynamic linking.  I want to know whether any mobile platforms support dynamic linking, such as Android or BlackBerry?

Comment: Why does it matter?  What does static linking of a library prevent that dynamic linking allows?

Comment: It matters when you are using GPL'd libraries in your application.  Static linking means your entire project has to comply with GPL which is a big problem for most companies trying to make a non-OSS.

Answer (score 1):

Android is built on Linux and supports dynamic linking.  However, it is unlikely that as an application developer you would end up using this functionality as any native code you use in your application will not be on the library path and consequently must be loaded explicitly.  That said, all calls to native methods that are part of the Android system are dynamically linked.

Answer (score 0):

windows mobile does

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can do it : [Dynamic linking](http://jiggawatt.org/badc0de/android/index.html#dynamic)